# picoCTF be-quick-or-be-dead-1 dcrypt simulation with python

Tags: decryption, python

This is `be-quick-or-be-dead-1` in `picoCTF` challenge ([Download](http://bayanbox.ir/info/7975794566083887573/be-quick-or-be-dead-1))

in this file we can see `decrypt_flag()` function, this function return this flag:

```
./be-quick-or-be-dead-1 
Calculating key...
Done calculating key
Printing flag:
picoCTF{why_bother_doing_unnecessary_computation_fedbb737}
```

i wanted to implement this function with python, and i wrote this code:

```
key=[0x2c,0x97,0xa5,0xe9]
i=0
flag=[0x5c,0xfe,0xc6,0x86,0x6e,0xc3,0xe3,0x92,0x59,0xff,0xdc,0xb6,0x4d,0xf8,0xd1,0x81,0x55,0xe5,0xfa,0x8d,0x5e,0xfe,0xcb,0x8e,0x6d,0xe2,0xcb,0x87,0x56,0xf4,0xc0,0x9a,0x47,0xf6,0xd7,0x90,0x6a,0xf4,0xca,0x84,0x46,0xe2,0xd1,0x88,0x43,0xfe,0xca,0x87,0x67,0xf1,0xc0,0x8d,0x5b,0xf5,0x92,0xda,0x0d,0xea]
while i < 58 :
    flag[i] = chr(flag[i] ^ key[(i&3)])
    i=i+1

print "".join(flag)
```

but when i run it, print wrong flag:

```
picoBTF{uhy_aothyr_dringAunnzceskaryFcomjutaoionKfedwb73!}
```

what is my problem?

thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution script is missing one vital part. if you look at the disassembly you could notice such part

```
0x004006ee      8b45ec         mov eax, dword [var_14h]
0x004006f1      83c001         add eax, 1
0x004006f4      8945ec         mov dword [var_14h], eax
```

Where `var_14h` the key is located so that this part is modifying the first entry in the `key` every time the algorithm loops over it (you can check few lines above those ones). 
You could modify your script like this:

> ➜  picoCTF cat solv.py

```
key=[0x2c,0x97,0xa5,0xe9]
i=0
flag=  [0x5c,0xfe,0xc6,0x86,0x6e,0xc3,0xe3,0x92,0x59,0xff,0xdc,0xb6,0x4d,0xf8,0xd1,0x81,0x55,0xe5,0xfa,0x8d,0x5e,0xfe,0xcb,0x8e,0x6d,0xe2,0xcb,0x87,0x56,0xf4,0xc0,0x9a,0x47,0xf6,0xd7,0x90,0x6a,0xf4,0xca,0x84,0x46,0xe2,0xd1,0x88,0x43,0xfe,0xca,0x87,0x67,0xf1,0xc0,0x8d,0x5b,0xf5,0x92,0xda,0x0d,0xea]
while i < 58 :
    flag[i] = chr(flag[i] ^ key[(i&3)])
    if i&3 == 0:
        key[0] = key[0] + 1
    i=i+1

print "".join(flag)
```

> ➜  picoCTF python solv.py 
>   picoCTF{why_bother_doing_unnecessary_computation_fedbb737}